# How to redirect to login page, if the process is not completed using angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have a Popup, that is used for device verification. 
So, once i click on login button after giving proper credentials, the popup opens if it is not trusted device, so i need to provide information then after successful validation, it redirects to home page.

My problem is, i clicked on login, so credentials needed for login is provided, and popup opens if its not trusted device, and if i refresh the page in middle of process, then it is redirecting to home page.

Can anyone help me how to solve this issue.

TS:

```
login(value: any) {
    let userName = value.email.trim();
    let passWord = value.password.trim();
    let password = Md5.hashStr(passWord)
    let params = { username: userName, password: password }
    this.authService.doLogin(params)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        else if (data.Body.Data.token && data.Body.Data.id != -2) {
          localStorage.setItem("userId_ls", data.Body.Data.userID)
          localStorage.setItem('accountId_ls', data.Body.Data.accountID)
          if (Cookie.get("DeviceUID") == null || this.DeviceUID == 'undefined') {
            this.isUserDevice = true;

          }
          else if (this.DeviceUID != null && this.DeviceUID != undefined && this.userDId != null) {
            let otpObj = { UserId: this.userDId, otp: "", Guid: this.DeviceUID, savedevice: "" }
            this._userService.confirmDevice(otpObj).subscribe(resp => {
                if(resp.message == "Invalid device.") {

                  Cookie.delete('DeviceUID');
                  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                  window.location.reload();

                } else {
                this.router.navigate(['/home']); }
            })
          }
        }
        else {
          console.log(data.message);
        }
      })

  }
```

Routing.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CanActivatedAuthGuard } from './core/security-guard/auth.guard';

let routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule' },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule' },
  // { path: '**', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule' },
  { path: 'register', loadChildren: './register/register.module#RegisterModule' },
  { path: 'accountActivation/:userId/:activationCode', loadChildren: './activation/activation.module#ActivationModule' },
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true, enableTracing: false }
    )
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

POPUP HTML:

```
 <p-dialog header="New Device Verification" [(visible)]="isUserDevice" [responsive]="true" showEffect="fade" [modal]="true"
    [width]="400">
    <div class="form-group row g-mb-25">
      <div class="col-sm-9 clear-fix">
        <label class="col-sm-8 col-form-label g-color-gray-dark-v2 g-font-weight-700 g-mb-10">Choose OTP type
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-9 clear-fix" *ngFor="let oType of otpTypes">
          <label class="form-check-inline u-check g-pl-25">
            <input type="radio" name="otpType" [value]="oType.otpType" (click)="chooseOtpType(oType)"> {{oType.otpType}}
          </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div *ngIf="isConfirmEmailOtp">
            <input class="form-control col-lg-12" type="email" [(ngModel)]="enterEmail" name="myEmail" #myEmail="ngModel" email pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{1,}@[a-zA-Z.-]{2,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}" (input)="submitButton &&submitButton.disabled = false"
              #emailOTP>
              <button (click)="generateEmailOtp(enterSms,enterEmail); submitButton.disabled = true;" class="btn pull-right otp"  #submitButton [disabled] = "enterEmail === ''&& enterSms === ''" >Send OTP</button>
            <div *ngIf="myEmail.errors && (myEmail.dirty || myEmail.touched)">
              <br>
              <div [hidden]="!myEmail.errors" class="error">
                Invalid Email.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="isSms">
            <input class="form-control col-lg-12" type="number" [(ngModel)]="enterSms" #smsOTP (input)="submitButton && submitButton.disabled = false">
            <button (click)="generateEmailOtp(enterSms,enterEmail); submitButton.disabled = true;" class="btn pull-right otp"  #submitButton [disabled] = "enterEmail === ''&& enterSms === ''" >Send OTP</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 row g-mb-10" *ngIf="isConfirmOtp">
          <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label g-color-gray-dark-v2 g-font-weight-700 text-sm-left g-mb-10 nopadd">Verify OTP:
            <span class="required">*</span>
          </label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="input-group g-brd-primary--focus">
              <input class="verifyPin" type="text" placeholder="Pin" [(ngModel)] = "otp">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <!-- End Login Verification -->
    <p-footer>
      <div class="col-sm-9 clear-fix saveDevice">
        <label class="form-check-inline u-check g-pl-25">
          <input class="g-hidden-xs-up g-pos-abs g-top-0 g-left-0" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)] = "checkboxSave">
          <div class="u-check-icon-checkbox-v4 g-absolute-centered--y g-left-0">
            <i class="fa" data-check-icon=""></i>
          </div>
          Save this device
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-helper-clearfix popup">
        <button type="button" pButton icon="fa-check" label="Save" class="btn u-btn-darkgray g-py-12 g-px-25 g-mr-10" (click)="cancelDevice()">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" pButton icon="fa-check" label="Save" class="btn u-btn-primary g-py-12 g-px-25" (click)="saveDeviceInfo(enterEmail, enterSms, otp,checkboxSave)" [disabled]="!otp">Ok</button>
      </div>
    </p-footer>
  </p-dialog>
```

TS:

```
saveDeviceInfo(enterEmail, enterSms, otp, checkboxSave) {
    var check = checkboxSave;
    var uID = localStorage.getItem('userId_ls');
    if (this.enterEmail != null && this.enterEmail != "") {
      let otpObj = { userId: uID, otp: otp }
      this._userService.confirmOtpEmail(otpObj).subscribe(resp => {
        if (resp.Body.Data == "OTP verified successfully") {
          let otpObj = { UserId: uID, otp: otp, Guid: "", savedevice: check, DeviceName: "webBrowser" }
          if(!this.DeviceUID && this.otp || checkboxSave == true) {
          this._userService.confirmDevice(otpObj).subscribe(resp => {
            if (resp) {
              Cookie.set('DeviceUID', resp.Guid);
              this.router.navigate(['/home']);
            }
          })
         }
        }
        else if (resp.Body.Data == "OTP is not valid.Please check the OTP") {
          this.enterEmail = "";
          this.enterSms = "";
          this.otp = "";
          this.msgs = [{ severity: 'error', summary: 'Error Message', detail: 'OTP is not valid.Please check the OTP' }];
          this.isUserDevice = false;
          this.isSms = false;
          this.isConfirmEmailOtp = false;
          this.isConfirmOtp = false;
          Cookie.delete('token');
          Cookie.delete('userType');
          Cookie.delete('userID');
          Cookie.delete('profilePic');
          Cookie.delete('Id');
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          window.location.reload();
        }
      })
    }

    if (this.enterSms != null && this.enterSms != "") {
      let otpObj = { userId: uID, otp: otp, isRequiredToken: this.isRequiredToken }
      this._userService.confirmOtpSMS(otpObj).subscribe(resp => {
        if (resp.Body.Data == "OTP verified successfully") {
          let otpObj = { UserId: uID, otp: otp, Guid: "", savedevice: check, DeviceName: "webBrowser" }
          if(!this.DeviceUID && this.otp || checkboxSave == true) {
          this._userService.confirmDevice(otpObj).subscribe(resp => {
            if (resp) {
              Cookie.set('DeviceUID', resp.Guid);
              this.router.navigate(['/home']);
            }
          })
        }
        } else if (resp.Header.Message == "User Does Not Exist For This OTP") {
          this.enterEmail = "";
          this.enterSms = "";
          this.otp = "";
          this.msgs = [{ severity: 'error', summary: 'Error Message', detail: 'User Does Not Exist For This OTP' }];
          this.isUserDevice = false;
          this.isSms = false;
          this.isConfirmEmailOtp = false;
          this.isConfirmOtp = false;
          Cookie.delete('token');
          Cookie.delete('userType');
          Cookie.delete('userID');
          Cookie.delete('profilePic');
          Cookie.delete('Id');
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          window.location.reload();
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

Here that popup function is coming after success of login, Please help.

Comment: @KarnanMuthukumar is this issue through, routes? i tried with conditions to route home page but nothing worked, please help

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when your popup window(I assuming it's a 'dialog' such as Angular Material dialog) comes out, the URL won't change. 
So, according to your description, your situation seems to be like:

-Just before you refresh, the url has already changed, or say you already successfully logged in. That's why it will navigate to the home page.

-The problem is you should have a routing guard everytime you enter a page to check if the user is logged in. Also, you will need authentification in your back-end.

The official routing documents of Angular explained almost everything pretty clearly and will be very useful. Here is the link: https://angular.io/guide/router

Hopes this helps you.

Comment: ya, after my successful login just before page redirecting i get popup so i am facing this issue. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

From this line ,

It must go to home page, after my popup is clicked on Ok button or if DeviceId is already present in cookies then it must go.

Handle popup ok click event (or) do like this using cookie

```
else{
   let deviceId= Cookie.get('DeviceId ');
    if(deviceId && deviceId!=null && deviceId!=undefined){
       this.router.navigate(['/home']); }
    }
}
```

show your _userService.confirmDevice which confirmation package you are used?

Comment: even now its going to home page

Comment: confirmDevice(data: any) {
    let body = JSON.stringify(data);
    this._spinnerService.show();
    return this._http.post(`${url.confirmDeviceOTP}`, body, this._httpRequestOptions.RequestOptions)
      .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())
      .catch(this._exceptionService.catchBadResponse)
      .finally(() => this._spinnerService.hide());
  }

Comment: is that what you wanted?